# Typescript: how to catch falsey values in variables declared by 'let'?

Tags: typescript

Here's my code so far:

```
let myVar: MyType;

if (isSth) {
  ...
  myVar = sth;
}
if (isSthElse) {
  ...
  myVar = sthElse;
}
...

function getSthImportant(myVar: MyType){
  ...
  return sthImportantDependingOnMyVar;
}

// No Type Error here even though myVar might be undefined:
const sthImportant = getSthImportant(myVar)
```

What's going on here: I don't know in advance what value to set `myVar` to, so I declare it and then set its value iff some condition is met. However, these conditions are **not exhaustive**, so `myVar` might not get set at all. The problem then is that the variable `myVar` needs to get passed to a function that does NOT handle an `undefined` value for `myVar`. I would therefore expect typescript to flag this as a problem (e.g. `myVar might be undefined. ts(123)`), but it doesn't. Even if I set the type as follows:

```
let myVar: MyType | undefined;
```

... typescript seems to think that `myVar` will never be falsey, even though it obviously can be, and won't flag a problem when I pass it to the function. My questions in summary are:

1. Why does typescript behave this way? I would expect typescript to complain that `myVal` has its type declared but then not initialized to a value of that type (as with `const`).
2. Is there a `tsconfig.json` option to require that `'let' declarations must be initialized.`, or some other way to achieve better type safety here?

Comment: A similar example gives the correct error in [the typescript playground.](https://tsplay.dev/NBzDzN) `Variable 'myVar' is used before being assigned.(2454)` Can you recreate your example there? Also maybe post your `tsconfig.json`. You may have some standard safety check disabled. Also in the playground you can play with different tsconfig settings and see when the error dissapears.

Comment: Hmmm. I do get that error when tsc is run from the terminal, but I don't get it when using VSCode. So I guess its a VSCode issue, but not sure what -- I had thought that VSCode and the terminal were configured identically...

Comment: There is a tsconfig setting effectively requiring variable initialization with a value `!= null` - `strictNullChecks` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html.

Comment: OK, got it. I had "include": [ ... ] defined in `tsconfig.json`, but this particular ts file wasn't included therein. Thanks to those who chimed in.